# Исправьте вывод работы кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Назовём натуральное число подходящим, если у него ровно **`3`** различных простых делителя.

Например, число **`180`** подходящее (его простые делители — **`2, 3 и 5`**), 
а число **`12`** — нет (у него только **`два`** различных простых делителя).

Определите количество подходящих чисел, принадлежащих отрезку `[50001; 90000]`, а также наименьшее из таких чисел.

В ответе запишите два целых числа: сначала количество, затем наименьшее число.

```
sp = set()
k=0
m=90001
for i in range(50001,90001):
    for j in range(2,int(i**0.5)+1):
        if i%j==0:
            sp.add(j)
        if len(sp)==3:
                k+=1
                if i<m:
                    m=i
                break
    sp.clear()
print(k,m)
```

- ответ:     **`15587 50001`**
- мой ответ: **`25287 50001`**

первое число не сходится,нет проверки на простоту делителя, как ее реализовать?

Comment: `2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 7 * 7 * 7 = 72030`. Ваш тест учитывает это число, хотя у него четыре простых делителя.

Comment: Между тем вы почти написали тест на простоту. Если бы `sp` считалось верно и если оно осталось пустым, то число простое.

Comment: Постройте таблицу простых решетом Эратосфена. Проверяйте делимость только на простые. `sp` не нужен, достаточно счётчика успешных делений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
k = 0
m = 90001

def simpleDividers(n):
   answer = []
   d = 2
   while d * d <= n:
       if n % d == 0:
           answer.append(d)
           n //= d
       else:
           d += 1
   if n > 1:
       answer.append(n)
   return answer

for i in range(50001, 90001):
    if len(set(simpleDividers(i))) == 3:
        k += 1 
        if i < m:
            m = i       
print(k, m)
```